# Css and images do not load on some pages because of the htacess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

in my htaccess file I have the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

and my index.php file looks like this

```
$url = '';
if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
    $url = explode('/', $_GET['url']);
}

if($url ==''){
    require 'home.php';

}elseif ($url[0] == 'article' AND !empty($url[1])) {
    $idArticle = $url[1];
    require 'article.php';
}elseif($url[0] == 'test'){
    require 'test.php';
}
else{
    require '404.php';
}
```

I have no problem on the test.php page where everything works correctly. But on my article pages the css, and the images do not load. I fixed the problem for the css with this line in my index.php:

```
elseif ($url[0] == 'article' AND $url[1] == 'style.css') {
   require 'style.css';
```

but I can't find solutions for the images. I have tried several things in the htacess but it does not work.
Example :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.zip|\.css|\.js)$
\\\\\\\\\\\\
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ [NC]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Avoid doing this in .htaccess or PHP if you can. Your current rule is "if it doesn't exist on disk let PHP figure this out", which is a very common rule and I'd say keep using that. When you generate links to your assets (CSS, JS, images, etc) use absolute root-relative URLs everywhere, so `/images/folder/1234/png` and your web server will automatically handle everything for you.

Comment: @anubhaav The url when there is an error is :
article/name where the name depends on the articles in my database.

Comment: @Chris Haas I tried that but my image folder is not even present in sources. Could this be because my .htaccess and index.php files are in the root?

Comment: It might help to show your folder structure. A very common format these days is for all public assets and their corresponding folders, along with .htaccess and index.php, to live in the site's root folder, and your PHP and template logic to live outside of that structure. This allows for some separation of concerns but it isn't an absolute requirements to do it 100% this way.

Comment: @Chris Haas   At the root I have a private folder with my php files, a public folder with firstly a css folder containing style.css and secondly an images folder. The htaccess and the index.php are in the root with the two other folders (public/private)

Comment: As a test, I created a htaccess file with just your above code, and in my php I'm just printing $_GET and have an img tag. When I access files that don't exist, they get sent to the php and I can get url from $_GET and the image tag and CSS file works.

Comment: _"I have tried several things in the htacess but it does not work. Example :"_ - your problem is not that the URLs for those assets get rewritten; the problem is that you changed the base URL that all _relative_ URLs will get resolved against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this in your html head tag `<base href="https://yourdomain.com/">`
It helps the page to understand where it should start looking for files
After using the tag in the `<head>` the any `src` attribute will now start its search from `https://yourdomain.com/the_directory_provided_in_the_attribute`. This way you have an absolute path to your resources and assets